# Custom Categories list in Wordpress with native list classes

Tags: php, wordpress, widget, categories

Trying to build a Custom Category List in the sidebar, succeeded with the first part, but cannot utilize wordpress `wp_list_categories()` properly.

Basically my widget creates an array of category ID's that are marked as "New"

```
Array
(
    [2] => Array
        (
            [title] => Blog Categories
            [categories] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 5
                )

        )

    [_multiwidget] => 1
)
```

Now what I need is to create a list of all categories where category with `ID - 1` and category with `ID - 5` will be displayed as

```
<li class="cat-item cat-item-1"><span style="color:red;">New!</span> <a href="/blog/category/mycategory1" title="mycategory special offer"><b>My Category 1</b></a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-3"><a href="/blog/category/mycategory2" title="mycategory special offer">My Category 2</a></li>
<li class="cat-item cat-item-5"><span style="color:red;">New!</span> <a href="/blog/category/mycategory3" title="mycategory special offer 3"><b>My Category 2</b></a></li>
```

I, for some reason cannot get anything done with use of

```
`wp_list_categories()` as it prints all categories out on the screen.

        $widget_instances = get_option('widget_custom_categories_widget');
        echo '<ul>';
        foreach ( $categories as $category ) {
            foreach ($widget_instances as $cat_key) {
                foreach ($cat_key['categories'] as $key) {
                    if($category->term_id == $key){
                        printf('<li class="cat-item cat-item-%3$s"><span style="color: red;">New!</span> <a href="%1$s"><strong>%2$s</strong></a></li>',
                            esc_url(get_category_link($category->term_id)),
                            esc_html($category->name),
                            esc_html($category->term_id)
                        );
                    }else{
                        printf('<li class="cat-item cat-item-%3$s"><a href="%1$s">%2$s</a></li>',
                            esc_url(get_category_link($category->term_id)),
                            esc_html($category->name),
                            esc_html($category->term_id)
                        );
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        echo '<ul>';
```

I am using the pice of the code above, but now I have another problem, all of the categories are printed twice, once with tag "New!" and once without.

Something to do with nested `foreach` statement, but cannot figure it out.

Any help or suggestions please

Comment: as I know, you can't add classes, wrap into some tags only some of the result. `wp_list_categories` will wrap all `categories` into span. you can use `get_categories()`: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_categories/, use query with args you need, and then create list of categories with foreach

Comment: Hello Samvel, thank you for your comment, I have just updated my question, please have a look and see if you can figure it out. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This trick may help you, if your array `$widget_instances` every time returns the array structured as you provided:

```
$cat_id = $widget_instances[2]['categories'];
echo '<ul>';
foreach ($categories as $category) {
    if (in_array($category->term_id, $cat_id)) {
        printf('<li class="cat-item cat-item-%3$s"><span style="color: red;">New!</span> <a href="%1$s"><strong>%2$s</strong></a></li>',
            esc_url(get_category_link($category->term_id)),
            esc_html($category->name),
            esc_html($category->term_id)
        );
    } else {
        printf('<li class="cat-item cat-item-%3$s"><a href="%1$s">%2$s</a></li>',
            esc_url(get_category_link($category->term_id)),
            esc_html($category->name),
            esc_html($category->term_id)
        );
    }
}
echo '<ul>';
```

Comment: Thanks!!! it worked, except that I have had to change `$cat_id = $widget_instances[0]['categories'];` to `$cat_id = $widget_instances[2]['categories'];`